# Macro to create an NSDecimalNumber from generic type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gcc, macros, clang

I have to create NSDecimalNumbers on the fly, but the problem is sometimes I am working with types like `int, float, double, etc` and other types I am working with types like `NSObject*, NSString*, etc`

Initializing an NSDecimalNumber is different for these different types, and it's very time consuming to type each out.

I was hoping to make a macro to sort it all quickly so I can just pass any type in and it will automatically sort it all out for me.

E.g.

`NSDecimalNumberFrom(5);`

`NSDecimalNumberFrom(@(5));`

`NSDecimalNumberFrom(@"5");`

---

```
#define NSDecimalNumberFrom(__v) ({\
NSDecimalNumber *__nsdn;\
if (strcmp(@encode(__typeof__(__v)),"i")==0 ||\
strcmp(@encode(__typeof__(__v)),"d")==0) {\
__nsdn = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal:[@(__v) decimalValue]];\
} else if (strcmp(@encode(__typeof__(__v)),"@")==0) {\
__nsdn = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal:[@([__v doubleValue]) decimalValue]];\
} else {\
NSLog(@"Unknown Type");\
raise(SIGSTOP);\
}\
__nsdn;\
})
```

I created the following macro which would work, it checks the typeof the passed value, if its "i" or "d" (e.g. int, float, double, etc) it creates the NSDecimalNumber with one initialization method, but if the typeof is "@" (e.g. NSString*, NSNumber*, etc) it creates it with another initialization method. This code, if compiled, would work ... the problem is compiler forbids me from running it because it knows the code inside the other conditionals would be invalid for the type I'm passing in (even though it would never be executed).

So how can I convince compiler to let me do this? Or is there another way?

Comment: yes error because the code has bugs even if typed as method.

Comment: @Ol Sen what bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by turning whatever was passed into a string, passing the wrong type into a string's format identifier will only cause a warning not an error, I was then able to suppress those warnings using pragma (since they'd never happen anyways, compiler just isn't smart enough to know that).

Viola,

## Macro:

```
    #define NSDecimalNumberFrom(__v) ({\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic push")\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Weverything\"")\
    NSString *__vString = @"0";\
    if (strcmp(@encode(__typeof__(__v)),"i")==0) {\
    __vString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", __v];\
    } else if (strcmp(@encode(__typeof__(__v)),"d")==0) {\
    __vString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", __v];\
    } else if (strcmp(@encode(__typeof__(__v)),"@")==0) {\
    __vString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", __v];\
    } else {\
    NSLog(@"Unknown Type");\
    raise(SIGSTOP);\
    }\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")\
    [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:__vString];\
    })
```

## In Use:

```
    NSDecimalNumber *a = NSDecimalNumberFrom(5);
    NSDecimalNumber *b = NSDecimalNumberFrom(@(6));
    NSDecimalNumber *c = NSDecimalNumberFrom(@"7");
    
    NSLog(@"%@", a);//logs 5
    NSLog(@"%@", b);//logs 6
    NSLog(@"%@", c);//logs 7
```

Comment: i like that. It has also some ironic touch. but hey it works.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please accept it (even if it is your question), it's perfectly valid. It helps to keep SO clean and it also saves time of other people, because they see it as answered and can help with other questions. Thanks.

Comment: @zrzka Was planning on it, was just waiting for the time limit to go away, S/O doesn't allow you to accept your own answer for 48 hours, had a reminder set.

Answer (score 0):

ok. had some fun tweeking around. Difference to *@Albert Renshaw*s version is it will return `NaN` if the input is nonsense.

```
#define ENTYP(__v,__typchar) (strcmp(@encode(__typeof__(__v)),__typchar)==0)
#define STRWF(FORMAT,__s) [NSString stringWithFormat:@FORMAT,__s];
#define NSDecimalNumberFrom(__v) ({\
_Pragma("clang diagnostic push")\
_Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Weverything\"")\
    NSString *__S = NULL;\
    if (ENTYP(__v,"i")) { __S = STRWF("%i", __v)\
    } else if (ENTYP(__v,"d")) { __S = STRWF("%f", __v)\
    } else if (ENTYP(__v,"@")) { __S = STRWF("%@", __v)\
    } else { __S = @"0"; }\
_Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")\
    [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:__S];\
})

-(void)test {
    NSDecimalNumber *i = NSDecimalNumberFrom(2);
    NSDecimalNumber *d = NSDecimalNumberFrom(5.0);
    NSDecimalNumber *s = NSDecimalNumberFrom(@"7");
    NSDecimalNumber *n = NSDecimalNumberFrom(@(13));
    NSDecimalNumber *quatsch = NSDecimalNumberFrom(@"quatsch");

    NSLog(@"i=%@ d=%@ s=%@ n=%@ quatsch=%@",i,d,s,n, quatsch);
    //i=2 d=5.0 s=7 n=13
}
```